# How to capture the packets that you send in Scapy?

Tags: python, network-programming, scapy, packet-sniffers, fuzzing

I am sending packets using:

```
     send(IP(dst="192.168.1.114")/fuzz(UDP()/NTP(version=4)), loop=1)
```

But I am not able to capture these packets in any other nearby machine (including the one with IP 192.168.1.114) which is on the same network. I am using wlan as my interface.

I also tried to sniff and then replay using scapy but I am still not able to capture those packets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this. Here is the checklist I made which might help others when dealing with replaying/fuzzing using scapy.

1. Check if all IP addresses you are dealing with are alive in the
   network (use ping)
2. Understand the difference between send() (layer 3)and sendp() (layer 2)
3. If mutating existing packet make sure to
   remove    the checksum (using 'del') and recalculate the checksum
   either using    show2() or using str to convert packets to string
   and then converting    them back to packets

Answer (score 0):

i would first try to capture the traffic on the sender machine with tcpdump while executing your program:

```
 tcpdump -i any udp dst 192.168.1.114
```

if you can see the traffic leaving the source host it may be that it does not arrive on the target host. UDP packets are the first packets to be dropped by any network device and as it is the nature of UDP it wont get retransmitted. if you are sure the packet leaves the source verify if it arrives at the target:

```
tcpdump -i any upd dst 192.168.1.114
```

Another point to check is your firewall settings. It could be either on the source or target system that your firewall is blocking those requests.

Comment: I can capture the traffic on the sender machine but not on the target host. I tried turning off the firewall as well. No sniffer is able to capture the packets being played by scapy.

Comment: @n0unc3 do you have some professional network switch in between on which you can dump traffic? may you can also see some counters on how many udp packets got dropped.

Answer (score 0):

You should use Wireshark, or the sniff function in Scapy and make it pretty print the contents on the screen:

```
sniff(lambda x:x.show())
```

Comment: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'function'